# Trying to get/set record

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am having problems getting and setting a value because I have introduced a third aspect into my code.

Previously I would do this to get/set in the record:

```
public virtual string MyString { get; set;}
```

and then in my part:

```
public string MyString
{
    get { return Record.MyString; }
    set { Record.MyString = value; }
}
```

and NHibernate would save my values in the DB (obviously my other code is not presented here for the sake of brevity).

Now I am trying to do a checkbox with a list. I have this for a checkbox:

```
public class MyPart : ContentPart<MyPartRecord>
{
    public MyPart()
    {
        MyList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
            .Cast<MyEnum>().Select(x =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString().ToUpper(), 
                Value = ((int)x).ToString() };
         }).ToList();
    }

    public IList<SelectListItem> MyList { get; set; }
    private string myCheckBox;

    // Record class contains the following commented code: 
    // public virtual string MyCheckBox { get; set;}

    // Trying to do this now here in MyPart class:
    public string MyCheckBox
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myCheckBox))
                return myCheckBox;
            // Tried the following commented code to get value:
            // Record.MyCheckBox = myCheckBox;
            return string.Join(",", MyList.Where(x => x.Selected)
                .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
        }
        set
        {
            myCheckBox = value;
            // Tried the following commented code to set value:
            // Record.MyCheckBox = myCheckBox;
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to assign the values in this case (getting/setting `myCheckBox` into `MyCheckBox`. It's being saved in the DB as null.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try `Record.MyCheckBox = value`

Comment: @DStanley I tried that a few days ago :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up just getting rid of the part and sticking with only a record - this allowed me to do the `get` and `set` in a view model, which worked out better (and was less confusing).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you'd be hiding the base `virtual` implementation of `MyCheckBox`.

I think instead you'd rather `override` the base:

```
public override String MyCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myCheckBox))
            return myCheckBox;
        // Tried the following commented code to get value:
        // Record.MyCheckBox = myCheckBox;
        return string.Join(",", MyList.Where(x => x.Selected)
            .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
    }
    set
    {
        myCheckBox = value;
        // Tried the following commented code to set value:
        // Record.MyCheckBox = myCheckBox;
    }
}
```

Thereby becoming the variable instead of obfuscating it?

Comment: That override won't work since the `public virtual string MyCheckBox { get; set; }` is in separate record class.  This is a part class.

Comment: Ok, now the suggestion to use `Record.MyCheckBox` makes sense.  I didn't catch that part.  So somewhere there's an instance of the `Part` class.  What's the tie back to `Record` then?  Should the `Part` class have a reference to a `Record` object that you can use to do something like `myRecord.MyCheckBox = myCheckBox`?  Assign the local member to the instance member?

Comment: I mistyped. It should be `MyPartyRecord` the tie in is `public class My Part : ContentPart<MyPartRecord> {...}`. I showed in the beginning how it is normally done (which works), it's just getting the `myCheckBox` into `MyCheckBox` that's got me stumped.